# Difference between "come by" and "come to my office"

Tags: verbs, prepositions

What is the difference between *come by* and *come to* with a destination?

1. Come by my office
2. Come to my office

Such a phrase might be used by a lecturer:

> If you want my help, please come **by** (or **to**) my office this evening.

Collins doesn't really help with [*come by*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-by) (it says "to obtain or find", which makes no sense here).

Comment: They are both correct. They mean different things, because the preposition is important. (By = alongside; to = arriving at my position). If you could edit your question to say what you want the "correct" sentence to mean, we may be able to help; but please also look up the prepositions in a dictionary.

Comment: Although there are reasonably strong arguments for considering 'come by' in this sense a multi-word verb (for one, it may be used intransitively), few if any would regard 'come to someone'  as other than verb + prepositional phrase.

Comment: @Nikhil I've incorporated your edit, added a realistic example and some research which indicates that something odd is going on with the phrase. I think this question asks what you want to know, but you can always edit it again if necessary.